# Processing video online (drawings/highlights)

Tags: javascript, video, video-processing

Is it possible to add some drawings and text highlights to video by JavaScript? or I need to use Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) With encoding new video :** 
You can use a tool like **[FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html)** to convert video to images. Infact FFmpeg can overlay text or other images over specific time in video and can also re-encode a new video file with new added changes. This is done in command line (or terminal) before you upload the videos to internet server...

**2) Without encoding new video :** 
If you want Youtube style "pop-ups" during playback then maybe try using some Javascript functions to track video play time and use `If/Else` to display text or images from a separate div or container. Use CSS layers to put video in bottom layer and pop-ups in above layer. Layers position is controlled by `z-index` (see: [**Z-index**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) tutorial).